# Only format df rows that are not NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, format

I have the following df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0.0137, 0.1987, 'Decimal('NaN')', 0.7653]})
```

Output:

```
        A
0  0.0137
1  0.1987
2     NaN
3  0.7653
```

I am trying to format each row from column `A`, using `.iloc` (because I have many columns in my actual code) into, e.g. 1.37%.

However, If I perform

```
df.iloc[:, 0] = (df.iloc[:, 0] * 100).astype(float).map('{:,.2f}%'.format)
```

All the NaN rows receive a trailing `'%'`, yielding `'NaN%'`

So if I try:

```
df.iloc[:, 0] = df.iloc[:, 0].apply(
        lambda x: (x * 100).astype(float).map('{:,.2f}%'.format) if not istinstance(x, Decimal)
        else None)
```

I get `IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds`.

How can I properly format every row of my `df` that is not a `Decimal(NaN)`?

Note: I'm specifically using df.iloc before the equal sign because I only want to inplace change those columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use df.loc to choose not NA rows and apply the logic you already have built

```
# your DF definition has 'NaN' as string, to converting it to np.nan
df.replace('NaN', np.nan, inplace=True)

# Select rows where the value for A is notna() and
# apply formatting

df.loc[df['A'].notna(), 'A']=(df.iloc[:, 0] * 100).astype(float).map('{:,.2f}%'.format)
df
```

```
    A
0   1.37%
1   19.87%
2   NaN
3   76.53%
```

Comment: I'm specifically using df.iloc before the equal sign because I only want to inplace change those columns. Any ideas as to how to implement your change with that? After implementing your idea, with my df.iloc, I'm still getting IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds.

Comment: @LuizScheuer, the changes are inplace, not exactly following what you meant?

Comment: Yep, you are correct. I have, however, made a change to the question, specifying that the type of the 'NaN' is a Decimal('NaN'), so I'm not sure what to use instead of .notna().

Comment: you meant 'df['A'].notna()' is failing? and not checking the presence of NaN?

Comment: Sorta correct, it is giving me 0.00% for the NaN values. and 1.00% for the non NaN values. Weird. here is the code I'm trying, instead of yours: `df.iloc[:, 17] = df.iloc[:, 17].notna().apply('{:,.2f}%'.format)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248908/discussion-between-naveed-and-luiz-scheuer).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
df.loc[~df['A'].isna(), 'A'] = (df.loc[~df['A'].isna(), 'A'] * 100).apply('{:,.2f}%'.format)
```

But careful, you are using `NaN` value as a string. I recommend to use numpy value. This should be:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0.0137, 0.1987, np.nan, 0.7653]})
df.loc[~df['A'].isna(), 'A'] = (df.loc[~df['A'].isna(), 'A'] * 100).apply('{:,.2f}%'.format)
```

Comment: Added a note to the bottom of the question that impacts your answer. And for whateve rreason, the NaNs are type float. I know, weird. They are actually supposed to be Decimal('NaN').

Comment: I don't understand what the note does to the answer. By using `loc`, you only change the selected column too

Comment: @ErnestBidouille, same approach as I posted :)

Comment: You guys are correct, all of the mistakes and misunderstandings in my questions come from the fact that I did understand .loc properly. Note, though: 'NaN' is a Decimal('NaN'). What to use instead of .notna()?